# Struts 2 Select Tag Default Value

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I'm creating a database record edit form using Struts.

```
<s:select id="status" name="newRecord.status" list="statusTypes" listKey="id" listValue="description" label="Status:" value="" /><br />
```

Example list:

```
Status' list: 
1 Open 
2 Closed 
3 Pending
```

I want to set a default value on the status field as the current status which is stored in `record.status` which contains the string representation e.g. `"Open"`.

If I set `value="%{record.status}` it doesn't work because that's not any list key. Is there a way I can set this value when I only have the string representation to work with?

Or should I redesign `record.status` to be an object with ID and `String`?

Comment: The value for the tag needs to be the _key_ which is the key part and not the value part. You can set it using javascript or, better, use a `Map` and lookup the key from the value you have.

Comment: @bmorris591 It is a map, the list is of the format id, description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize the value of the `newRecord.status` that should be a separate property that contains the list key value. Then simply set the default `value="%{record.status}"`. When I said the property I mean the bean property that is accessible via OGNL.

Comment: Fair enough, I expected as much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a hash instead of a list.  Notice

```
listKey="id" listValue="description"
```

Then you can set the value = the key

Comment: Can you give an example? From my record I only have a string status (e.g. 'Open') which is what I need to set as the value... so I need some way of getting the relevant key.

Comment: You need to change your record so that you have a key, value pair instead of just a value.  Just give a key to each item in your list and store it in a hash