# set default value in dropdown using struts

Tags: java, struts2

I have a form  that has a field functional area that is a drop down 
I am inserting data in database by selecting data from drop down (drop down get data from database). Now I  am updating data so I want set drop down default. value have to  that inserted data from drop down

I am using following code but I am not getting right  value 

      Functional Area:

```
      <s:textfield name="funArea" />  // getting  data from database

       <s:select id="funarea" list="functionList" name="functionalArea" headerKey="-1" 
        cssStyle="width:162px;" headerValue="<s:textfield name='funArea'/>" 
          onchange="showState(this.value)">  </s:select>   // setting database value on drop down's default selected value 
            </td>
```

but i am getting this

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `value="Your value"` inside select tag.
more information:

[Official link](http://struts.apache.org/docs/select.html)

Two related stackoverflow questions:

[struts2 select tag default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300135/struts-2-select-tag-default-value)

[struts2 select default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674483/struts-2-select-default-value)